# -std=c++11 flag increases executable size

Tags: c, c++11, g++

Having C style code in C++ like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hi\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Executable size normally is: 8.50 KB. (Optimized for size with -Os -s)

When added -std=c++11, the size grows to 32.50 KB.

Does it have anything to do with stdio.h or why does the size change?

Tested with g++ version 6.3.0 on code::blocks. OS: Windows 8.1 pro

Comment: "C code in C++" is actually a C++ code.

Comment: I meant C style code but yes it's C++ code as well.

Comment: What version of gcc?  I can't reproduce with gcc 7.3.0, it gives me bitwise identical 7.3KiB files in C++03, 11, and 14 modes.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either, gcc 4.8 `ls -h` gives me 6.3K for `./a.out` with `g++ -std=c++11 -Os -s code.cpp`

Comment: I have g++ 6.3.0

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 8.1 pro. I'll try it out on linux too in a moment

Comment: @Levi: Try running `objdump -t your_binary | c++filt` or whatever is the Windows equivalent. Also, maybe it's some weird GCC-on-Windows issue.

Comment: @einpoklum thanks for the suggestion. I can't replicate it on linux so probably a weird windows case.